# Understanding the interplay between Fréchet derivative and ordinary derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $Y$ be a Banach space. Consider the real-valued fucnion $\phi \in C^\infty _c (\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open. Let $y\in Y$. Then can we say $\phi y \in C^\infty _c (\Omega; Y)$? We note that  $ C^\infty _c (\Omega; Y)$ is the space of all functions $u$ such that for each $x \in \Omega$, the function $u(x,.) \in Y$ and the mapping $ x \in \Omega \mapsto  u(x,.) \in Y$ is infinitely differentiable in Fréchet derivative sense. The difficulty I am having is to justify that $\phi y$ is infinitely differentiable in Fréchet sense.

Comment: Consider the bilinear continuous function $\mathbf{R} \times \mathrm{Y} \to \mathrm{Y}$ given by $(\lambda, y) \mapsto \lambda y.$ Apply the Chain rule.

Comment: Thanks for the nice comment. Maybe it is not clear from my question, but here $y$  is a fixed vector in $Y$. Then it is enough to consider the continuous linear map $ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow Y$ given by $ \lambda \mapsto \lambda y$. Since continuous linear maps are smooth and here $\phi$ is smooth, as you suggested, by chain rule we are done. Please let me know if the argument makes sense.